# log_format in nginx.conf being ignored

Tags: nginx

Total NGINX beginner here.

My logs currently look like:

> 92.21.236.47 - - [08/Jan/2017:00:48:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"

When I add the following line in the default /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user xxx[$time_local]xxx '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; 
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

(the access_log and error_log lines already exist in the default config, I have put these here solely for context).

I then restart NGINX with:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

I now expect my logs to change and in particular to show the xxx literal values used .. xxx[$time_local]xxx .. but my change makes no difference.

If I change **log_format main** to **log_format combined** then the server won't restart.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

changing ..

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
```

to ..

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
```

fixed it.

where **main** is the name of the log_format as defined at ..

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user xxx[$time_local]xxx '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

Comment: Exactly same problem, same solution: if the **name** parameter is set in log_format, you have to give it to log_format

Comment: I understand this to be very old but hopefully someone finds it helpful
we need to add the log_format in the nginx.conf file which is the default config file of nginx. 
And mostly we will have a custom config enabled as well, in my case I did have , and I needed to append what @danday74 mentioned above to my custom config file present within sites-available and after this we can validate whether the changes are correct my using `nginx -t` and if all correct we can ask nginx to reload the config file instead of doing a restart by using command 
`nginx -s reload`

Answer (score 19):

Its late to reply but it might be useful for those who are still hanging in this prolem.

Write the `log_format` directives outsider the `server {}`

The whole code would be like this

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user xxx[$time_local]xxx '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
server {
      listen 80;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/<your_domain>_access.log main; 
}
```

Here main represents what fields nginx should include while writing the logs.

For more detail information, Please look in the official documentation
[Sampling Requests with NGINX Conditional Logging](https://www.nginx.com/blog/sampling-requests-with-nginx-conditional-logging/)

Comment: Indeed. Besides, this documentation tell the context where `log_format` is accepted (http, only): https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Answer (score 0):

2 above answers tried but didnt help. and i realized that

above the `log_format` line in my nginx.conf,
`server` brace was not closed.
and it gave me the same error.